# Display Custom Options from parent product in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-options, pdp

I have custom router and if there is a custom attribute in url, simple product is loaded instead of configurable parent. Simple product is loading correctly, but i cant manage to load custom options from configurable parent. Is this possible or simple has to have these options assigned as well?

Comment: Please explain more what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I used below extension in one of my site for achive this functionality. its costly but the only way to achive this.

https://firebearstudio.com/improved-configurable-products-for-magento-2.html